# How to make Thunderbolt port work for DELL docking station with 16.04?

Tags: usb, dell, ethernet, thunderbolt, usb-c

I use a DELL Precision 5510 laptop computer which is labelled 'Ubuntu Edition'. As most modern laptops this machine doesn't have an Ethernet port for LAN connection but a Thunderbolt port for various signals.

DELL offers [matching docking stations](https://skinflint.co.uk/dell-thunderbolt-dock-tb15-452-bcfr-a1398615.html) for their laptop series which connect via Thunderbolt plug. To my regret, I don't get Ubuntu 16.04 working with the full power of the Thunderbolt connection. At the moment, power is the only source that my laptop receives. Neither internet connection via ethernet port, nor keyboards or mice connected via USB, nor any audio signals are received in the laptop when plugged into the dock.

Plus, if I connect an Ethernet-Thunderbolt-Adapter to the computer, LAN connection is not recognized as well. So it's not an issue of the dock but rather of Ubuntu to process Thunderbolt interface transmission, I guess.

Any ideas where to start to get this working?

**Update**

Today, I had a long chat with DELL support staff. Comes out, that there's neither BIOS nor driver support for Ubuntu Linux - despite offering *Ubuntu Editions* for sale.

Anyway, while there's a comprehensive download section for Windows users, there're neither BIOS updates nor hardware drivers for Linux available. Windows users can make their Thunderbolt Dock work following [this guide](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301969).

Now, my question is more precisely: Can or will we get someday drivers for Ubuntu which enable usage of the docking station with an DELL Ubuntu laptop? Where could I start looking for suitable drivers?

**Update 2**

Almost half a year later now I suddenly receive emails from DELL support, offering to exchange the TB15 Dock with the new TB16 Dock at no cost. Several connectivity issues would've been reported and DELL seems to take this as a cause for this hardware exchange programme.

Comment: I have the Precision 5510, running Linux Mint. The dongle for ethernet to USB-C/Thunderbolt works out of the box for both Mint 17.3 Rosa (with a 4.0
series kernel) and Mint 18 Sarah. On the other hand, no charging through the USB-C port -- that is supposed to work with the XPS 13, but not with the XPS 15/Precision 5510 (answer from Dell tech support). So I have not tried a Thunderbolt docking station, since I'd still have to run a separate power cable to the laptop.
Note: although the ethernet dongle worked for me with BIOS 1.2.10, you may want to get the latest BIOS (1.2.14).

Comment: @BernardMoret: Charging does work through the USB-C/Thunderbolt port via th DELL TB Dock for my Precision 5510. So far, I haven't been able to make a BIOS update without having Windows installed. That would be another question I guess, but did you update your BIOS from a plain Ubuntu / Mint setup? If so, how?

Comment: For the BIOS update you can simply download the firmware update file to a FAT32 formatted USB and select the "BIOS Flash Update" option from the F12 boot selection menu. It should let you select the file and flash it from the USB drive.